# Disabled splitter in qt designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I'm using qt 4.8.0 on windows 7.
When I open qt designer and create widget in it, I cannot set 'Lay Out in a vertical/horizontal in Splitter'. Also there is no Splitter in a Layouts widget box.
All other layouts are working well.

Have anyone run into same or similar problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to select two or more widgets and then use the layout -> vertical/horizontal splitter option. This will give designer enough context to be able to perform the operation.

Also note that the selected widgets cannot be part of a layout already.  If they are, you need to break the layout first (`layout->Break Layout` in context menu).

Answer (score 0):

It's in the contextual menu that appears on right-click in the body of the widget.

You can establish the widget's layout including splitter there.

EDIT: Sorry, I misunderstood in a rapid first-reading. Are you saying it doesn't appear in the right-click menu, between the other layout options?